# 100 Rep for a 'new user'?

Tags: support, new-users

I noticed a new user with a rep of 103. But when I checked the profile they appear to have no other SE profile and have only been a contributor on BH for 4 days.

I have noticed this happen previously. Is it possible to 're-invent' oneself and carry the privileged 100 starter points across to a 'new identity' ?

[I don't wish to draw attention unfairly to any individual, so I have preferred not to link.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Site association bonus rep (100) and hidden community.

---

Users with [site association bonus rep](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) will start with 101 rep on new site.

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

---

Hiding communities can be accessed on [this link](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current).

When someone accessing the user's profile on the hidden community, the "Network Profile" and other sites' account will be hidden, making it look like the user is only having an account on that site only.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has happened to me that when I asked a question about what I thought was a bug I was told the answer was dependent on my rep on another SE site. There was a comment saying that the commenter could not see my linked accounts so it is possible that someone has linked accounts that you don't see.

Has the user asked or answered questions?

103 would be equal to 1 initial + 10 * answer votes + 1 suggested edit accepted. There are other ways to get it but you see the idea.